# Getting a margin even if not added in css?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

[image]

In the above image a margin is being added at the top of Title. In Css padding top is 10 px but for some unknown reason a **margin is there above the Post title.** where it is written "Appropriately synergize..."

HTML

```
<div id="featued" class="site-featured">
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="images/featured-image.jpg"></img></div>
            <div class="featured-title">
              Appropriately synergize cross-media applications for frictionless meta-services
            </div>
            <p class="featured-body">
              Completely foster interdependent growth strategies with leading-edge methods of empowerment. Dramatically fashion end-to-end total linkage before real-time partnerships. Uniquely develop sustainable materials whereas web-enabled resources. Progressively incubate pandemic web-readiness after exceptional synergy. Enthusiastically exploit client-focused imperatives rather than premier communities.

              Progressively target bleeding-edge imperatives and enterprise strategic theme areas. Distinctively simplify out-of-the-box strategic theme areas for user-centric deliverables. Compellingly aggregate high-payoff ROI vis-a-vis distributed portals. Competently productivate covalent e-services before just in time infrastructures. Monotonectally fabricate orthogonal innovation vis-a-vis focused leadership.
            </p>
          </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.site-featured{
    background-color: #79a6b2;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    height: 268px;
    color: #fff;
}

.featured-title{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.site-featured .featured-image{
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

Note:- I am already using Reset.css

> Additional screenshot for more clarity:

[image]

Comment: I'd say the whitespace is due to: `<div class="featured-title">______________Appropriately`

Comment: I have created your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Mtr/ .Point out where is the margin problem

Comment: <img /> is a self closing tag! no "</img>" needed! only <img src="" alt="" />

Comment: @user2648239 margin problem is above featured-title.

Comment: Its not clear from you question.. where is the unexpected white space or margin???

Answer (score 0):

By default brower will some margi and padding for the tags, so better to use any css 
  **CSS Tools: Reset CSS**  meyerweb

hope it will help you

```
 .featured-title {
  display: flex;
 }
```

Comment: hope it will help you, check it now

Comment: no, it is same. There is a liitle gap between the text and div roof.

Comment: can you provide the online link

Comment: it's fine, i have moved on. don't want to give more time to this issue. Just added top margin of 5px to image.